# Не запускается PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Перестал запускаться **PyCharm**. Пишет, чтобы установить переменную окружения `JAVA_HOME`, хотя у меня все задано.Перезагрузка,переустановка не помогают.

Скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Моя переменная, которая задана]

[image: это переменная Path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробовали обновить пакет Microsoft Visual C++ ?
 [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/RU-RU/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: Нет.А при чем он тут? Тем более 2015 года

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, для того.. - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-do-i-reinstall-msvcr100dll/8d7c8355-fe0b-44e9-b94f-83ec819a9cb6?auth=1

Comment: от души,господа))